# JQuery Alert When Bar Code is scanned

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

I want a web page that pops up a JavaScript alert when a bar code scan is done. I don't want to tie the event to any visible control such as a textbox so thus, I won't have focus on any control to capture the scan input. Can this be done with JQuery?

Comment: Question lacks detail and effort.

Comment: I personally disagree with the downvotes and closing as not a real question. I understand the complaint, but at the same time, I've wondered this same thing, and even with a considerable level of experience under my belt, I do not have a definitive answer or method at this point. It's conceivable that someone else will have a similar question, happen on this page, and maybe find some useful information. If the issue is that you don't understand how barcode scanners work, don't blame the original poster...

Comment: In fact I just found this: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-barcodelistener/ if I am not mistaken is pretty much an answer to the original question. Which does indicate a slight lack of research, since it was easy for me to find, but at the same time, it is still "a real question" ... Don't sweat the haters, Bob ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to capture key input on the entire page. For example:

```
$(document.body).on('keypress',function(e){
    console.log(e.keyCode);
});
```

I don't know if the character input from the scanner creates the same keypress events in the DOM as actual key presses, but I'm guessing that it might. My scanner died, but I would be interested to know if this type of technique is feasible.

Keep in mind: without a text input you would have to write your own code to figure out what input constituted a "scanned code" versus other key input, previous key input, and so on. That shouldn't be terribly hard since a barcode scanner usually inputs very quickly and also outputs a carriage return at the end.

Comment: Almost worked, got me on the right path. I used this:           jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $(document).keypress(function (e) {
                alert(e.which);
            });
        });